# How to rewrite Location header with NGinx when there is a mapping from subdomain to subfolder?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to install keycloak behind a NGinx.

From point of view of NGinx, keycloak can be reached with this url : https://auth.private.

From outside (Internet), NGinx can be reached from https://my.organisation, I want it performs this url mapping in order to reach keycloak from outside :

- https://my.organisation/private/auth -> https://auth.private

Then, I use this nginx configuration to performs it :

```
location ~ ^/private/auth(/?.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://auth.private/$1;
}
```

When I try to reach https://my.organisation/private/auth with my browser (firefox), it **fails** because my browser receives a redirection to https://auth.private/auth and it can't reach https://auth.private. I try to curl to keycloak url from NGinx host with command `curl -svkL https://auth.private`, there are two redirections :

- First redirection : HTTP 302 to https://auth.tkeir/auth
- Second redirection : HTTP 303 to https://auth.tkeir/auth/

**My questions** :

- When there is a redirection, how to rewrite *Location* header with my outside url ?
- How to manage all redirections easily in my NGinx conf file ?

For information : Keycloak in installed into a Kubernetes cluster with a NGinx ingress (another one), but I think it's not important.

Comment: what's your server block look like, mainly its root path?

Comment: Looks like your capture will add a forward slash if it's included in the capture. So maybe don't add forward slash to the proxy_pass. If you don't need proxy_pass specifically, try `return 301 https://auth.private$1;`